# Errors in estimates of intercept and slope in least squares method

Tags: statistics, least-squares

We want to find the line $y = mx + c$ that best "fits" the list of points $$(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), ... (x_i, y_i), ... (x_n, y_n).$$ For each point there is no uncertiainty in $x$ and each $y_i$ has uncertainty $\sigma_i$

By minimizing the squares differences

$$[y_i - (mx_i + c)]^2$$

At first for $m$ and then for $c$ and then making a system we can find $m$ and $c.$
This I understand.

My doubt is how can we find uncertainties for $m$ and $c?$

My textbook just says that we can sum the partial derivatives of $m$ with respect to each $y_i$ multiplied by $\sigma_i^2$ (the uncertainty of the given $y_i)$ and performs the calculation in just one line.

Could anyone explain in more detail how to calculate such errors? I think seeing an example with 3 points would make me understand the concept without the trouble of too much notation.

Here is the calculation of my book that gives me trouble:

$$Var[m] = \sum (\frac{dm}{dY_i})^2*\sigma_{Y_i}^2 =$$
$$= (x_i/\sigma_(Y_i)^2- \overline x / \sigma_{Y_i}^2 )^2 * \frac{1}{Var[x]^2}*\frac{1}{\sum\frac{1}{\sigma_{Y_i}^2}} =$$
$$= \frac{1}{Var[x]*\sum\frac{1}{\sigma_{Y_i}^2}}$$

At the start of the second line my book uses $x_i$ outside of any summation symbol, I think that is an error.

Comment: Can you evaluate $(\frac{dm}{dY_i})^2$?

Comment: @BruceET no that's exactly the problem, the derivative of $m = cov(x,y) / var(x) = \overline xy - \overline x * \overline y / ( \overline x^2 - (\overline x)^2 )$ is giving me trouble. In my calculation I get the summation of derivatives of an expression that itself  contains summations. I cannot go forward in that calculation

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ denote the matrix with 1s in the first column and $x_i$ in the second column. Then $(m,c) = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$. Let $r$ denote the first row of $(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$, then
$$m=r^T y = \sum_i r_i y_i.$$
Assuming the uncertainties of $y_i$ are uncorrelated, you get $$\sigma^2(m)=\sum_i r_i^2 \sigma^2(y_i).$$
You can do the same for $c$ using the second row of $(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$.

Comment: What does (m, c) represent? I did not study this topic in relation to matrixes so it is very hard for me to follow, could you please explicitly point out how those matrixes represent (or do the same job as) partial derivatives?

Comment: $(m,c)$ is a vector whose first component is $m$; the first displayed equation shows the relation between $m$ and $y$ and makes it trivial to compute partial derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but I doubt that a demonstration with $n = 3$ will
do much for your intuition. In that case, by the time we estimate the slope and
intercept, we do not have a good estimate of variability.
Maybe it will help to show several regressions with $n = 20.$

**Model.** Suppose
$x_i = i,$ for $i = 1, 2, \dots, 20.$ That is the $x$'s are just the
integers from $1$ through $20.$ If the true y-intercept is $\beta_0 = 4$
and the true slope is $\beta_1 = 1.5,$ then the regression model is
$$Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 + e_i,$$
where the errors are independently $e_i \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu=0,\, \sigma=2).$

Then we can generate the $Y_i$ in R statistical software, according to this known model, as follows.

```
set.seed(622);  n= 20;  b0 = 4;  b1 = 1.5;  sg = 2;  x = 1:n
y = b0 + b1*x + rnorm(n, 0, sg)
plot(x, y, pch=19);  abline(a = b0, b=b1, col="green3")
```

The 20 points $(x_i, Y_i)$ are plotted below along with the known linear
relationship $Y_i = 4 + 1.5x_i$ and the variability of the points shows
the effect of the normal errors $e_i$.

[image]

**Regression line.** How accurately can the regression line (least squares line)
recover the information about our model? In R, we find the estimated y-intercept
$\hat\beta_0 = 3.519$ and the estimated slope $\hat\beta_1 = 1.551,$ as follows:

```
lm(y ~ x)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
      3.519        1.551
```

The figure below shows the same data points and true model (green) as above,
along with the regression line (dashed red). The regression line is not a
perfect copy of the true model, but it is close enough to be useful. Of course,
a different experiment using the same model would have different random errors $e_i$, so another experiment would give a slightly different regression line.

[image]

**Distribution of estimates of slope $\beta_1.$** Essentially, your question
asks for the distribution of the estimates of the y-intercept and slope.
For simplicity, we focus just on the slope. We repeat the regression procedure
100,000 times. Each time we use $n=20,\, \beta_0 = 4,\, \beta_1 = 1.5,$ and $\sigma=2.$
However, on each iteration we simulate new new errors $e_i,$ in order to try to
understand the variability in the distribution of $\hat\beta_1.$

```
 set.seed(622);  m = 10^5;  n = 20;  x = 1:n;  b0 = 4;  b1=1.5;  sg = 2
 b1.hat = replicate(m, lm(b0 + b1*x + rnorm(n,0,sg) ~ x)$coef[2])
 mean(b1.hat);  sd(b1.hat)
 ## 1.499939    # Expected(b1.hat) aprx 1.5
 ## 0.07764731  # SD(b1.hat)
 hist(b1.hat, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main="Distribution of Slope Estimates")
```

[image]

The simulation suggests that $E(\hat\beta_1) = \beta_1 = 1.5.$
According to statistical theory, $$SD(\hat\beta_1) = \sigma/\sqrt{(n-1)S_x^2}
= 2/\sqrt{665} = 0.07756,$$ which is well-approximated (by `0.07765`) in
the simulation.

The histogram seems to be approximately normal in shape.
More precisely,

$$\frac{\hat\beta_2-\beta_0}{S_{Y|x}/\sqrt{(n-1)S_x^2}}\sim
\mathsf{T}(\nu = n-2),$$

Student's t distribution with $n-2$ degrees of freedom,
where $S_{Y|x}$ is an estimate of $\sigma = 2$ (using $x$'s and $Y$'s). So the exact distribution of
$\hat \beta_1$ is based on a t distribution that is nearly normal. In practical applications, the t distribution can be used to make a 95% confidence interval for the unknown true slope $\beta_1.$

Comment: Thanks a lot for illustrating with an example, but I still do not get the connection of the error on the slope and the partial derivatives.

Comment: The partial derivatives with respect to $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ are used to derive the least squares line. Maybe you could show the _exact probability relationship_ for which you seek an intuitive justification. What is "intuitive" depends on one's mathematical level, and we have no clue about that from your Question.

Comment: Excuse me for not including the exact equation before, I did not include it because I thought my book made an error in it. Now it is at the bottom of the question, I seek explanation on that equation in particular.